# CHARINDEX with integer

Tags: sql, charindex

Hi I have a select which works great where I use CHARINDEX on a varchar column, but when I try it on a integer column I get the following error;

*Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.*

Below I have listed both queries.

stremail is varchar 
intEmployeeID in integer

```
**below returns results as aspected**
SELECT  intEmployeeID
FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees]
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + strEmail + ',', ',' +  REPLACE('test@gmail.com,  test2@gmail.com', ' ', '') + ',') > 0


**below I get an error if I'm trying to select on a integer column**
SELECT  intEmployeeID
FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees]
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + intEmployeeID + ',', ',' +  REPLACE('1, 2', ' ', '') + ',') > 0
```

Any help would be most greatful.

Comment: Even though the first 2 answers helped me, I used the answer provided by @Matt. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  intEmployeeID
FROM [dbo].[tblEmployees]
WHERE CHARINDEX(',' + cast(intEmployeeID as nvarchar(max)) + ',', ',' +  REPLACE('1, 2', ' ', '') + ',') > 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt I used your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ cast(intEmployeeID as varchar)+
```

Cast intEmployeeID as varchar

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly convert the integer to a character string, otherwise it compiles the `+` operators as *integer addition* instead of *string concatenation* :

```
CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),intEmployeeID) + ',', ',' +  REPLACE('1, 2', ' ', '') + ',')
```